# I need help making my program more streamline, as I am sure where are many things I am missing

Tags: python

Testing if a string is a palindrome or not and should be O(n) runtime. We cannot use any import statements or any other helper methods can be used.

So basically my program is to receive an input which is a string that can contain anything. If something in that string is not part of the alphabet it is to ignore it, such as spaces or commas. My program currently works but seems like there should be ways that I could make my program better, by either reducing code or something that I am just unaware of.

An example would be with the string ' E.U.V, vV V,U,E'  so the first thing mine does is it goes to string[0] which is just a space and shorts to recalling itself with isPalindrome(string[1]:len(string)-1) so isPalindrome('E.U.V, vV V,U,E').

```
def isPalindrome (string):
    if len(string) <=1:                 # Basecase to check if the string has less than or equal to 1 element remaining in the string so that the recursion may end
            return True
    if string.isalpha():                    # Checks if the string is all letters of the alphabet and proceeds if true
            if (string[0].lower() == string[len(string)-1].lower()):                    # Compares the lowercase form of the first element and the last element and if they are equal the program will proceed
                    return isPalindrome(string[1:len(string)-1])                    # Function is calling itself with the next elements in the string
            else:
                    return False
    else:
            if string[0].isalpha():                 # Checks if the first element in the string is part of the alphabet and proceeds if true
                    if string[len(string)-1].isalpha():                 # Checks if the last element of the string is part of the element and proceeds if true
                            if (string[0].lower()== string[len(string)-1].lower()):                 # Both the first and last element have been confirmed as being part of the alphabet and will not be compared to each other, program proceeds if true
                                    return isPalindrome(string[1:len(string)-1])                    # Function is calling itself with the next elements in the string
                            else:
                                    return False                    # Program return false when some elements do not equal each other
                    else:
                            return isPalindrome(string[0:len(string)-1])                    # Function is calling itself with the next elements in the string
            else:
                    return isPalindrome(string[1:len(string)])                  # Function is calling itself with the next elements in the string
```

Comment: Please make the titles of your questions less vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is a lot of code for palindrome checking.

Essentially, a palindrome is a string that equals itself if read from the end. You can check that with the slice notation on strings. Now to clean your string from everything that is not a letter, a small list comprehension will do.

```
def isPalindrome(text):
    text = "".join([x for x in text if x.isalpha()])
    return text==text[::-1]
```

Comment: Awesome, and thank you very much for the information as it was extremely helpful.